# Best Way to Design DB Products and Attributes for Multi-Vendor E-commerce

Tags: sql, database, laravel, database-design, e-commerce

I am designing a website that will host possibly hundreds, if not thousands of vendors at some point.

The problem:
Each vendor will have a plethora of products, many with different attributes.(screwdrivers have a phillips point, with a shank length of 'x', overall length of 'x', while bearings have 'od','id', 'rpm', and greases etc may have max temp of 'x', material of 'xy and z'.

Initially, I wanted to make a table for each vendor, however, I quickly realize thats not practical on the large scale.

Second, I thought, perhaps an attribute table for each vendor with some null values for values that do not apply to the item.

Third, I thought perhaps, ONE attribute table with many null values for any attribute that doesn't apply. This seems the easiest and most practical, however, this could mean a LOT of null values, as I may have hundreds of thousands of different products.

Can anyone provide any guidance on this particular situation. I have seen many with the second option, however, most answers I run into do not seem to match the scale and possible complexity of what I am trying to do. Perhaps, I am overthinking it, but I will be using Laravel and the eloquent ORM to map this out and simplicity is key in my world, but practicality and performance on scale is something I want to plan for in the beginning to prevent superfluous pains down the road.

Thanks guys,

Edward

Comment: I dont think you want to split this up by vendors, as you assuming that vendors are only providing one type of product. My 5 second consideration would have a generic ProductAttribute table, and a ProductType table that defines what attributes are required for each ProductType. Then each row in your Product table will have an associated set of ProductAttributes that cover length, headtype, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. That does seem like a considerably better option. I appreciate your 5 second lol